# How to check for hyperlinks in ms word using perl?

Tags: perl, hyperlink, ms-word

I want to search for hyperlinks in MS word doc using perl.  Is there any way to find out hyperlink in MS Word doc?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~snkwatt/Text-Extract-Word-0.04/lib/Text/Extract/Word.pm http://search.cpan.org/~amiri/MSWord-ToHTML-0.010/lib/MSWord/ToHTML.pm http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/HTML-SimpleLinkExtor-1.26/lib/HTML/SimpleLinkExtor.pm http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution,

```
my $Hyperlinks = $document->Hyperlinks();
    my $enumerate1 = new Win32::OLE::Enum($Hyperlinks);
    my $count1 = $Hyperlinks->{Count};
    print " count1 --> $count1 \n";

    while(defined($Hyperlinks = $enumerate1->Next()))
   {
        my $text = $Hyperlinks->{Range}->{Text};
        print "text is $text \n";
    }
```